# Unable to retrieve full facebook url used to open mobile application on FB viralities clicks

Tags: facebook, trigger.io, url-scheme, deep-linking

I'm currently trying to work with urlhandler setting, in order to know which original URL was used to open my app when coming from FB app. (see deep linking section in [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/#deeplink))

I tried any url scheme (my package name, activity class & path, http url) without any success in my Forge app. The urlhandler listener in my native app is never triggered.

Could anyone lead me to a correct use of [urlhandler](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/urlhandler.html) forge module ?

---

EDIT: I managed to make the urlhandler event listener being triggered during initial application's launch... but with an exception:

```
    Native call "urlhandler.urlLoaded" with task.params: {}
    [   INFO] W/Forge   (23672): Error while executing API method: urlhandler.urlLoaded
    [   INFO] D/Forge   (23672): Returning: {"content":{"type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE",
"message":"Forge Java error: NullPointerException: null",
"full_error":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.modules.urlhandler.API.urlLoaded(API.java:14)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp.callJavaFromJavaScript(ForgeApp.java:194)\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeJSBridge.callJavaFromJavaScript(ForgeJSBridge.java:8)\n\tat android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)\n\tat android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)\n\tat android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:92)\n\tat android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:108)\n\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)\n\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)\n\tat android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1057)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)\n"},"status":"error","callid":"BDEEEAE6-1A7A-4608-A75F-CE53F2DB2677"}
```

Here is the urlscheme I entered to get this error: `content://<package_name>`

I'm still unable to get any event triggered when my app is already opened, paused then resumed from a Facebook virality

Answer (score 1):

Edit: a fix for the NullPointerException went into platform version v1.4.34 - see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-34.

Answer for the unedited question follows:

---

An example from one of our test apps: in the App Config we have the urlhandler module configured to listen for the `forgetest` scheme:

```
"urlhandler": {
  "scheme": "forgetest"
}
```

Then, opening a link like `<a href="forgetest://a/b/c">`, your urlhandler callback would be invoked with `"forgetest://a/b/c"` as its argument.